# php mysql result multidimensional array to custom table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following tables on mysql:

```
daily : daily_id, date, student_id, class_id, amount1, amount2, is_done
students : student_id, person_id, ....
persons : person_id, person_name,....
classes : class_id, class
```

Now I can select a range from this table with dates between 2 values (let's say a week). This provides me with a multidimensional array I guess (I'm a noob, feel pity...)

I would like to be able to expand the results and group them on a table like this:

```
                  Sunday      |     Monday      |    Tuesday      | ........
personname1 | class | amount1 | class | amount1 | class | amount1 | ........
personname2 | class | amount1 | class | amount1 | class | amount1 | ........
```

Now, if a student was not present on a specific day on this week or he didn't manage to gather any amount then we should just show something like 'Absent' and $ 0.00 on that day.

I have been trying for a long time now to iterate through the array and get my results correctly on such a table with no luck whatsoever... I am sure that this is due to being noob and all but I've run out of ideas, I need some good pointers, I can't do it without help... All I get is a row of results like:

```
(row1) daily_id, date, student_id, class_id, amount1, .....
(row2) daily_id, date, student_id, class_id, amount1, ..... etc
```

My code so far:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM daily WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-03-13' AND '2016-03-19'";
    $selected_result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>
<table>
<? php
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected_result)) {
            $daily_id = $row['daily_id'];
            $date = $row['date'];
            $class_id = $row['class_id'];
            $student_id = $row['student_id'];
            $amount1 = $row['amount1'];
            $amount2 = $row['amount2'];
            $is_done = $row['is_done'];
 ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $daily_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $student_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $class_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $amount1; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $amount2; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $is_done; ?></td>
                </tr>
<?php
    } // closing the while loop
  ?>
</table>
```

Could anyone please point me on the right direction?

Comment: The solution provided by @Technoh below is the closest to the required result. However, the table produced using the loops is not correct and the rows, even though they contain all the required data, are not ordered as per my example above... Is there anyone that could jump in and lend a hand?

Answer (score 0):

To show the data as you represent it you need to select data from more than one table. I suggest you read up on `JOIN` syntax, you could read a [tutorial on the subject](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) as the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) can be hard to read sometimes. Also, your table could use some optimizing but that is beside the point of this question.

That being said, here is, I think, what you are looking to achieve. First the SQL:

```
SELECT
    persons.person_name,
    daily.date,
    daily.amount1
    classes.class
FROM
    persons LEFT JOIN
    students ON persons.person_id = students.person_id RIGHT JOIN
    daily ON students.student_id = daily.student_id LEFT JOIN
    classes ON daily.class_id = classes.class_id
WHERE
    daily.date BETWEEN '2016-03-13' AND '2016-03-19'
ORDER BY
    persons.person_id ASC,
    daily.date ASC
```

Then your HTML/PHP code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th colspan="2">Monday</th>
        <th colspan="2">Tuesday</th>
        <th colspan="2">Wednesday</th>
        <th colspan="2">Thursday</th>
        <th colspan="2">Friday</th>
        <th colspan="2">Saturday</th>
        <th colspan="2">Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<?php
    $current_date = strtotime( '2016-03-13' );
    $maximum_date = strtotime( '2016-03-19' );
    $one_day = 24 * 3600; // 24 hours of 3600 seconds each.
    $current_person = '';

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $selected_result ) ) :
        if( $current_person != $row['person_name'] && $current_person != '' ) :
            // Fill in the empty days at the end of the week.
            while( $current_date <= $maximum_date ) :
?>
        <td>Absent</td>
        <td>$0.00</td>
<?php
            endwhile;

            $current_date = strtotime( '2016-03-13' );
?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<?php
        endif;

        $row_date = strtotime( $row['date'] );
?>
        <td><?php echo $row['person_name']; ?></td>
<?php
        // Fill in an empty day.
        if( $row_date > $current_date ) :
?>
        <td>Absent</td>
        <td>$0.00</td>
<?php
        else : 
?>
        <td><?php echo $row['class']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['amount1']; ?></td>
<?php
        endif;

        $current_date += $one_day;
        $current_person = $row['person_name'];
?>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This might be a bit circumvoluted, I wrote parts of it while on the phone. The format is bloated to help you understand but you could certainly simplify it.

**Important**: this assumes, as you did in your question, that every `person` has only one `class` per day. If that is not the case then you need a different approach.

Comment: Spot on! Exactly what I was looking for. Your code needs some refining. There are some errors like "$row['date] missing a ' after the date".Also the table created a <tr> should be in a while loop cause the next record just adds on the right side on one row only. Can you spot it? I have no idea where since I still try to familiarize my self with your code.

Comment: Not at first glance, I'll take another look in a few minutes. I did, however, correct the SQL to group by `person` and to fix the `$row['date']` issue. Is the extra `<tr>` on the first row of the data or the last one?

Comment: Like I said above, the table needs some sorting while populating with data. I now notice that the row shows, student name (under Name), then class and amount (under Monday), then student name and class (under Tuesday) which is wrong, then amount and name (under Wednesday) etc. Something needs a little tweaking and we're set!

Comment: Shouldn't the last </tr> on your code be inside the while loop? I only get 1 row with all the data with the way that your code is. But if I put the last </tr> inside the while loop (2-3 lines above) then I only get the first 2 columns populated with the wrong data.

Comment: Can you post the resulting html (ideally only the table) in a jsfiddle or pastebin? I'll try to play with it.

Comment: Ok I can see right away that I messed the query again, I just updated it, please try it and replace the pastebin if it's not fixed.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/7SHzL02y I can also see that we have no data with Absent or 0.00 even though not all students were present every day. I hope this helps you a little bit in spotting the error in the looping.

Comment: Regarding your important note, that "every person has only one class per day", I noticed that on my data I had instances that I had one person on more than one class per day but I cleared that data as this was something that I intended to limit on anyway. I guess though that it is OK if the same class gets visited by more than one person per day. If not, I can limit that as well!

Comment: The same class can be linked to one person, the problem is if you have more than one class per day per person then your table doesn't work anymore and the resulting HTML code becomes a lot more complex.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the added line `$current_person = $row['person_name'];`. This should help you have more than one `<tr>`. Let me know and pastebin the result if there are still issues.

Comment: Can't paste the table cause that lead to an infinite loop and the page never ends loading. I got in total 3 rows and the rest was looping on the right. It looks like 6 extra cells on the right of the table on the first 2 rows (bearing name, class, and amount 2 times) and infinite on the third one. The third row is full of Absent and $0.00 and sometimes some names

Comment: I run your query through phpmyadmin and here is a sample of the results (I thought it might help you)...

Panagiotis, 2016-03-13, 30.00, Class 1
Panagiotis, 2016-03-14, 30.00, Class 1
Panagiotis, 2016-03-15, 30.00, Class 5

Comment: I know that maybe I ask too much but would you take another look at that table and try to sort the data as needed? I'm afraid that this is beyond my abilities for now...

Comment: Well the major problem is that with your data you cannot get a table like the one in your question, which means most of my code will need to be rewritten. You should update your question with what you would want according to the data you really have.

Answer (score 0):

very close to result.

here is what u need to change :

1. create a html string by concatenating first then echo.
   example:

> ```
> <?php
> $html="<table>";
> while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected_result)) {
> $html.="<tr><td>$row['daily_id']</td><td>$row['class_id']</td></tr>";
> // ad more inside that
> }
> $html.="</table>";
> echo $html;
> ?>
> ```

second thing u need is to work on structure.
no of columns < no of rows , just suggestion

:: u can make days(7 in number) heading for rows . and person(class,amt) as cols heading(4 in number)

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking for